# CRichEditCtrl selects all text when it gets focus

Tags: c++, mfc, focus, selection, cricheditctrl

I had a dialog with a menu and a CTabCtrl.  The CTabCtrl had one tab, which contained a CDialog.  In turn, that contained a few static texts and a CRichEditCtrl.  There was no particular issue with the window gaining and losing focus.

I since added a second identical tab, and now every time the tab is changed, all text in the CRichEditCtrl is apparently selected.  It is shown in an inverted color scheme and all text is replaced should you hit a key.

The description of flag ECO_NOHIDESEL, says (emphasis mine):

> Negates the default behavior for an edit control. The default behavior
>   hides the selection when the control loses the input focus and **shows
>   the selection when the control receives the input focus.** If you
>   specify ECO_NOHIDESEL, the selected text is inverted, even if the
>   control does not have the focus.

"shows the selection" to me sounds like "show whatever the selection was the last time this control had the focus," which is not what's happening.  Normally nothing is selected before focus is lost, but if I do try to leave a selection, go back to the other tab and return, the entire text, as usual, is selected.

Can this selection be prevented?

void EditorDialog::OnTabSelChange( NMHDR * phdr, LRESULT* pResult ) {

```
  CTabCtrl* ptab = (CTabCtrl*) GetDlgItem( IDC_TAB );

  int iPageActive = ptab->GetCurSel();

  if ( iPageActive >= appage.N() ) {
      AKS( AKSWarn, "got tab change to tab %d when I only have %d ppages", iPageActive, appage.N() );
      return;
  }

  ppageActive = appage[ iPageActive ];

  SetActivePagePos();

  SCWinUtilSetWindowTextVA( this, "Editor: %s", ppageActive->pszFileName );
}



void EditorDialog::SetActivePagePos() {

  // STEP 1: Make the proper tab page visible.

  for ( int i = 0; i < appage.N(); i++ )
      appage[i]->ShowWindow( SW_HIDE );
  ppageActive->ShowWindow( SW_SHOW );

  // STEP 2: Make the new tab page the right size and position.

  CTabCtrl* ptab = (CTabCtrl*) GetDlgItem( IDC_TAB );

  CRect rectTab, rectItem;

  ptab->GetClientRect( &rectTab );
  ptab->GetItemRect( 0, &rectItem );

  int iPageX = rectItem.left   + 2;
  int iPageY = rectItem.bottom + 4;
  int iPageW = rectTab.right   - 2 - iPageX;
  int iPageH = rectTab.bottom  - 2 - iPageY;

  ppageActive->SetWindowPos( &wndTop, iPageX, iPageY, iPageW, iPageH, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOZORDER );

  // STEP 3: Give the window focus and let it know to redraw.

  ppageActive->SetFocus();

  // When the tab changes the entire content of the RichEdit is selected for some reason.
  // As a workaround I manually clear the selection.
  CRichEditCtrl* prich = (CRichEditCtrl*) ppageActive->GetDlgItem( IDC_PATCH );
  prich->SetSel(-1,-1);

  // Redrawing just the prich, or the ppageActive, or the ptab, doesn't
  // cause the RichEdit to redraw correctly, but Redrawing the entire dialog does.
  RedrawWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default behavior for Edit and Rich Edit controls is to make the selection *invisible* when the control does not have the input focus and only make it visible when the control has the focus. The selection is not, however, *changed*. The `ES_NOHIDESEL` style overrides this default behavior and causes the selection to *always* appear in the control, regardless of whether or not it has the focus. You have certainly seen this behavior before: it is what both Microsoft Word and Visual Studio do.

As such, your understanding of the SDK documentation is perfectly correct. Unfortunately, there is another aspect of the Rich Edit control's behavior that is getting in the way. Whenever an Edit or Rich Edit control *hosted in a dialog box* receives the focus, it automatically selects all of its text, obliterating the current caret position in the process. The `ES_NOHIDESEL` does not have any effect on this behavior; it just changes whether or not the selection is *visible* when the control is unfocused. You can certainly override this select-all-on-focus behavior by doing as [IInspectable suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20884852/366904) and [subclassing the control to customize its handling of the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031114-00/?p=41823).

But there is a *much* simpler solution. Along the same lines as `ES_NOHIDESEL`, **you want to set the [`ES_SAVESEL` style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774367.aspx)** for the control upon creation. Although you can set `ES_NOHIDESEL` in the resource editor ("No Hide Selection"), there is no equivalent property for `ES_SAVESEL`. You can manually add it to the RC file, but there's no guarantee that it won't be obliterated when Visual Studio regenerates that file.

Alternatively, you can send the Rich Edit control a `EM_SETOPTIONS` message specifying the **`ECO_SAVESEL`** option. In MFC, the [`SetOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20z1432s.aspx) member function wraps the sending of this message. For example, in your `OnInitDialog` function, you might have the following:

```
m_myRichEditCtrl.SetOptions(ECOOP_OR, ECO_SAVESEL);  // maintain selection across focus events
```

Answer (score 4):

The default behavior for Edit and RichEdit controls is to select the entire contents when they gain focus. [`ES_NOHIDESEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774367.aspx) does not modify this behavior, but simply instructs the control to always show its selection, even if it doesn't have the input focus.

To change the default behavior of the RichEdit control to **retain** its selection you have to derive from it and provide your custom [`OnGetDlgCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t83978eh.aspx) implementation:

```
UINT RichEditSelectionPreserving::OnGetDlgCode() {
    // Call the base class implementation
    UINT code = CRichEditCtrl::OnGetDlgCode();
    // And mask out the undesired feature
    code = code & ~DLGC_HASSETSEL;
    return code;
}
```

Comment: Thanks IInspectable.  To be clear my main goal was to avoid the auto-selection.  (Preserving previous selection across loss of focus would only be of limited utility.)  Your suggestion does exactly what I hoped for, thanks!  (Sorry I don't have enough reputation points to bump it up.)

Its funny that now I have your suggestion, Google turns up several good links with the keyword DLGC_HASSETSEL.  Yet Visual Studio 2008 seems to have no help on this topic whatsoever.  Can you tell me how you ever learned of this?  Is there any good book I should read that explains these things?

Comment: @SwissFrank Information on the *Dialog Manager* is scarce. The MSDN provides an overview on [Dialog Boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588.aspx). While not complete it gives a good summary. The Old New Thing has a multi-(9?)-part series on the topic, starting with [The dialog manager, part 1: Warm-ups](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/03/29/403298.aspx). Type *"Dialog Manager"* into the search box to discover the other parts.